# Strange symbol on my desktop

Tags: symbols

[image]

This strange symbol appeared on my desktop today. It includes a button saying "OK" which only appears if you go over it with the mouse. I can't remove the symbol but everything else works normal, including the Internet. Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

This is a stock image representing the terrestrial globe. This might give you a hint
of the product that is issuing it.

You may also use
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
to find the process the is issuing this window: Drag and release the bull's-eye icon
over this window to find the process. Double-click it to find its folder, which
will identify it better. Process Explorer can also show the column of "Company Name".

Once you identify the product, either uninstall it, or it may have a setting for
stopping this behavior.